# Crear instalador sin problemas c# y sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hola amigos programadores , tengo una consulta

Yo cree un proyecto en c# con sql y me gustaría que la misma aplicación me instale el sql ya probe utilizando advanced installer y en algunos casos funciona pero en otros no, pero lo que qusiera saber es si hay alguna version de sql que no de problemas con el lenjuage y que sea compatible  con todos los sistemas operativos y que no de muchos problemas al moemento de hacer la instalacion.

Ya que lo que quiero lograr es que la app, cualquier persona la pueda instalar sin necesidad de tener conocimientos en informática o programación.

Comment: La pregunta no se adapta al formato del sitio, y probablemente termine como cerrada. Por otro lado, `Sql Server`, no es un producto para instalaciones del todo sencillas, y el universo de sistemas que existen, lo hace más difícil. Si el instalador oficial, tiene dificultades con el lenguaje, el resto de opciones lo van a tener más complicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías utilizar [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15) y realizar la instalación silenciosa : `msiexec /i SqlLocalDB.msi /qn IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES`

advanced installer no lo he probado, pero si realicé un instalador inno setup y funciona a la perfección.